# UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction not working

Tags: objective-c, ios, animation

the problem is this : i have the class `NKIngredient` which is a subclass of `UIImageView`. I've implemented the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods in it and set the `userInteractionEnabled` on `YES`. But the major problem is that when i animate my `NKIngredient` instance in a view controller i need the object can be touched during the animation. And this is impossible! 
The interface of `NKIngredient` :

```
@protocol NKIngredientDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)ingredientTouched;

@end

@interface NKIngredient : UIImageView {
    CGPoint touchStart;

}

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <NKIngredientDelegate> delegate;

- (void)animate:(void (^)(void))animationBlock;

@end
```

The implementation file :

```
@implementation NKIngredient

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

//Viene chiamato questo metodo se l'oggetto è disegnato come nib
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    NSLog(@"NKIngredient initWithCoder");
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:aDecoder]) {
        [self setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    }
    return self;
}

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (BOOL)becomeFirstResponder {
    return YES;
}

- (void)animate:(void (^)(void))animationBlock {
    [UIView animateWithDuration:8.0 delay:0.0 options:UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent & UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction animations:animationBlock completion:^ (BOOL finished) {
        NSLog(@"Completed");
    }];
}

#pragma mark - Touch interaction

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    //NSLog(@"Touches began");
    [_delegate ingredientTouched];
    touchStart = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    NSLog(@"Touched");
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"Touches moved");
    CGPoint point = [[touches anyObject] locationInView:self];
    self.center = CGPointMake(self.center.x + point.x - touchStart.x, self.center.y + point.y - touchStart.y);
}

@end
```

And this is what i do in my view controller :

```
ingredient = [[NKIngredient alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, -50, 34, 45)];
    [ingredient setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"liv1_Burro.png"]];
    [ingredient setUserInteractionEnabled:YES];
    [[self view] addSubview:ingredient];


    [ingredient animate:^ (void) {
        [ingredient setFrame:CGRectMake(20, 200, 34, 45)];
    }];
```

Some solution to get the touch even when the object is animating? Because when the `NKIngredient` is stationary the `touchesBegan/Moved/Ended` methods works.

Comment: What version of iOS is this running on?

Comment: u may try UIGestureRecognizer class.

Comment: I'm using iOS 6. UIGestureRecognizer is a good solution, but i need to move the object. So, the user can drag the object. Is it possible to do with UIGestureRecognizer? @Ishank

Comment: You can use `UIPanGestureRecognizer` to move views by dragging...

Comment: Good! With UIPanGestureRecognizer works perfect, but not when the object is animating..there is a solution?

Comment: perhaps, u can put a transparent view on top of the view which is being Animated and manage touches on the Transparent view rather than the animating view.Could not find a better way without using openGL/Cocos2D.

Answer (score 1):

You must bitwise OR the flags together, not AND...

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent & UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
```

should be

```
UIViewAnimationOptionAllowAnimatedContent | UIViewAnimationOptionAllowUserInteraction
```

or else they will cancel each other out. Also I've noticed with animation touches only register at the point where the animation will finish...

Comment: Ok, changed. But the situation doesn't change. If i use the touchesBegan code in the UIViewController class it works. But i need to implement it in the NKIngredient class, subclass of UIImageView